# Random array selection

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm making a tic tac toe(without matrix), and I have a question about this.

Say that my input here was "5":

```
printf(" 1 | 2 | 3 \n");
printf("___|___|___\n");
printf(" 4 | 5 | 6 \n");
printf("___|___|___\n");
printf(" 7 | 8 | 9 \n");
printf("   |   |   \n");
printf("\n");
```

I want that the A.I. select a random box, excluding my "5" input. I'm doing the random thing with:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
int randIndex = rand() % 8; 
    if (movement == 5 && i == 0){
            xslot[randIndex] = 'O';
            steps = 1;
    }
```

I don't know how to exclude the "5" from this random selection.

This is my array:

```
char xslot[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
```

Thank you

Edit: complete code:

```
main()
{
    int movimento,passos;
    bool passo1=false,passo2=false,passo3=false,passo4=false,passo5=false;
    char oslot[9] = "O";    
    char xslot[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    printf("\n\n");

    printf(" 1 | 2 | 3 \n");
    printf("___|___|___\n");
    printf(" 4 | 5 | 6 \n");
    printf("___|___|___\n");
    printf(" 7 | 8 | 9 \n");
    printf("   |   |   \n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Digite o numero do seu movimento:");
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%i",&movimento);

            if (movimento == 1){
                xslot[0] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 2){
                xslot[1] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 3){
                xslot[2] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 4){
                xslot[3] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 5){
                xslot[4] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 6){
                xslot[5] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 7){
                xslot[6] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 8){
                xslot[7] = 'X';
            } else if (movimento == 9){
                xslot[8] = 'X';
            }   

            //INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL

            int randIndex = rand() % 8;

            if (movimento == 5 && i == 0){
                    xslot[randIndex] = 'O';
                    passos = 1;
            }
```

Comment: What's `rand() % 8`??? Where does `8` come from? What's `movement`? What's `i`?

Comment: Added the entire code

Comment: @Vitor Presa Isn't the aim of the code to select the best possible winning position rather than a random number ? If numbers are always random the computer would almost never win.

Comment: I'm learning yet so i'm going slowly hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with the available selections and "shrink" it every time a selection is chosen:

```
size_t numSelections = 9;
int selections [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
while (numSelections > 0) {
  size_t const next = rand() % numSelections;
  --numSelections;
  // move selected selection out of valid array range
  int const selection = selections [next];
  selections [next] = selections [numSelections];
  printf("Selected %d\n", selection);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/ywIrho)

Every time you select a value you move it "out" of the valid range of the array, moving the (not selected, but now outside of the range) value back into the valid array range:

```
1 2 3 4|
;; select the 3, shrink valid range
1 2 3|4
;; move 3 out, bring 4 back in
1 2 4|x
```

In my example above the selection happens randomly, but you could easily modify it to - for example - alternate between random and user directed selection to implement your game

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove it, you just have to ignore it

```
int randIndex
while( (randIndex = rand() % 9) != 4 );
```

You should also check whether the position is valid, and you should write to `oslot`

```
while( (randIndex = rand() % 9) != 4 && oslot[randIndex] != 'O');
oslot[randIndex] = 'O';
```